# Full Regex for selecting Date Time

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I want to select all formats for date and time and i need a full regex.
currently i am using this regex:

```
public const string DateTimeRegex = @"\b(?<datetime>" +
        // Date part
        @"((" +
            @"(\d{1,2}[\/\-\.]\d{1,2}[\/\-\.]\d{2}(\d{2})?)" +
            @"|(\d{1,2}\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-zA-Z]*,?\s+\d{2}\d{2}?)" +
            @"|((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-zA-Z]*\s+\d{1,2},?\s+\d{2}\d{2}?)" +
            @"|(\d{4}\-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})" +
        @")" +
        // Optional time part
        @"(" +
            @"[T\s]?\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2}(\.\d+)?)?(([AP]M)|([\+\-][12]?\d:\d{1,2})|Z)?" +
        @")?)"  +
    @")\b";
```

I have a little problem with this regex, it correctly selects all the dates in the following format, but it cannot select the time (only a few are selected)

```
11/17/2022 11:36 AM 
  1/6/2023  6:19 PM
 11/3/2022 12:06 PM
  Saturday, December 10, 2022  8:07 AM
    Thursday, January 5, 2023  3:27 AM
```

output:

```
11/17/2022
1/6/2023
11/3/2022
December 10, 2022
January 5, 2023
```

so i need to use another regex for selecting time part

```
public const string DateTimeRegex2 = @"(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2}(\.\d+)?)?(([AP]M)|([\+\-][12]?\d:\d{1,2})|Z)?)";
```

I tried to merge these 2 regex but unfortunately it doesn't work and date and time are not selected correctly.

now i have a date like this:

```
25-Dec-2022 12:36
```

and None of the regexes can not select it.

so I want a regex that selects the following formats:

```
25-Dec-2022
25-Dec-2022 12:36
25-Dec-2022 12:36 PM
11/17/2022
11/17/2022 12:36
11/17/2022 12:36 PM
1/6/2023
1/6/2023 12:36
1/6/2023 12:36 PM
11/3/2022
11/3/2022 12:36
11/3/2022 12:36 PM
December 10, 2022
December 10, 2022 12:36
December 10, 2022 12:36 PM
January 5, 2023
January 5, 2023 12:36
January 5, 2023 12:36 PM
```

If any other formats are available, I need to identify them

Comment: https://ihateregex.io/expr/date

Comment: @depperm tnx but is not support all my formats, just a few

Comment: There are so many more possible formats.. What about `January 5th, 2023` or `05. März 2023` etc etc.

Comment: Oh, you have no idea the can of worms you're trying to open.

Comment: Also: is 1/6 January 6th or June 1st? Because depending on where you're from you will answer different, and it will likely surprise you how much of the world disagrees with you regardless of which format you're used to, even within your own country.

Comment: When it comes down to it, **you should not let users enter arbitrary strings for dates/times**. Make them use a calendar picker or similar. If you must let them enter arbitrary strings, always provide immediate and unambiguous feedback on how the value is interpreted, and then only save the interpreted value in the unambiguous and consistent format.

Comment: Finally, even if you somehow succeed at this, the resulting expression is gonna be an unmaintainable nightmare to update over time. Regex is just not the right tool for the job in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following RegEx?

`(?<date>(?:\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|\d{1,2}-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}|(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|Jule|August|September|October|November|December) \d{1,2}, \d{4}))(?:\s+(?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(?: (?:AM|PM))?))?`

Comment: tnx, between date and time we have 2 space how i can fix this?

Comment: Updated for multiple spaces between date and time